# Unhappy with donation process at Ubuntu.com download page

Tags: 12.04

My question is with contributing to Ubuntu:

I tried to donate $25 this morning before downloading 12.04.3 LTS (you kinda force people to it). I wanted to donate, as I've done before, without any other returns than the privilege of using the software. I thought I was entering billing info so that my credit card would be charged directly, but instead it appears the site forces me to go through PayPal! While I do have a PayPal account, I don't like to use it much. So I ended up canceling the contribution. I sure don't know why Ubuntu sets up the donation feature thusly - it turns me off.
If you want people to contribute voluntarily, make it easy for them and not force one to use a certain payment method.

Answer (score 3):

snip

> If you want people to contribute voluntarily,

snip

Well, we are not the people who work for Ubuntu, we are volunteers here.

The [Contact Us](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/contact-us) page linked from Ubuntu's website states, in part,

> If you have suggestions or corrections for ubuntu.com or
>   canonical.com, email us at webmaster@ubuntu.com or
>   webmaster@canonical.com.

which is the best way to contact Ubuntu folks about this issue.

> I thought I was entering billing info so that my credit card would be charged directly,

When I look at the pre-download page, the [donation button](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/questions?distro=desktop&bits=64&release=lts) clearly states **PayPal** and immediately to its left is the no donation link. Therefore, don't see how you could have thought you were setting up a charge to your card account, and the address collection is so the Ubuntu T-shirt (part of the deal on that page) could be shipped to you.